# Finding a value inside a nested array having only a string with the keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one array that contains some settings that looks like basically like this:

```
$defaults = array(
   'variable' => 'value', 
   'thearray' => array(
                  'foo' => 'bar'
                  'myvar' => array('morevars' => 'morevalues');
                  );
);
```

On another file, i get a string with the first level key and it's childs to check if there is a value attached to it. Using the array above, i'd get something like this:

```
$option = "thearray['myvar']['morevars']";
```

I need to keep this string with a similar format to the above because I also need to pass it to another function that saves to a database and having it in an array's format comes in handy.

My question is, having the array and the string above, how can i check for both, existance and value of the given key inside the array? array_key_exists doesn't seem to work below the first level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple function to parse your key-string and examine the array like:

```
function array_deep_exists($array, $key)
{
    $keys = preg_split("/'\\]|\\['/", $key, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    foreach ($keys as $key)
    {
        if ( ! array_key_exists($key, $array))
        {
            return false;
        }
        $array = $array[$key];
    }

    return true;
}

// Example usage
$defaults = array(
    'variable' => 'value', 
    'thearray' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'myvar' => array('morevars' => 'morevalues')
    )
);
$option = "thearray['myvar']['morevars']";
$exists = array_deep_exists($defaults, $option);
var_dump($exists);  // bool(true)
```

Finally, to get the value (if it exists) return `$array` where the above returns `true`.

Note that if your array might contain `false`, then when returning the value you'll have to be careful to differentiate no-matching-value from a successful false value.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. I'm not sure i like that it depends on the format of the string being exact but i guess that is the nature of the problem.

I noticed the false values problem, but they are using 0 for those anyway, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: It only depends on the string format being exact if you want it to. It would be trivial to change the code which assigns the list of keys accept any other format(s).

Answer (score -1):

You need to [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) this code, and use [isset](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function in an eval string, and don't forget to add $ character in right place before code eval

example:

```
eval("echo isset(\$defaults['varname']['varname2']);")
```

this will echo 0 or 1 (false or true) You can do anything in eval, like a php source

Comment: You should avoid using `eval()` whenever possible, especially when handling data from external sources, as it is a very major security risk (possibility of code injection), and therefore this is a bad solution.

Comment: i know it's a bad solution, but situation exampled in a question is even more bad technique to do things, if it's done that way, i assume it's done by purpes and knowing what are threats of this kind of programming...  solution i proposed just works, it may not be a perfect one ...